# Alarm not going off when device is sleeping for a few hours (on Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-alarms

I created a simple alarmclock that works great and shows a notification as a simple reminder on a specific time chosen by the user (if the device is not awake, it plays the notification sound).

But when i use it as an alarm to wake up in the morning, it fails to play the notification sound.

It's hard to test because the device has to be locked for a few hours. I think it has something to do with Doze, but i'm not sure. Also, if the device is charging overnight it plays the alarm just fine.

After waking the device in the morning manually, the notification gets received...

The code on setting the alarm:

```
        // Create an intent that will be wrapped in PendingIntent
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",id);

        // Create the pending intent and wrap our intent
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),(int)id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //get the alarm manager
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
        {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
        }
        else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime() , pendingIntent);
        }
        else alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime() , pendingIntent);


        //go back to the main activity
        onBackPressed();
```

My AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.e("ALARMRECEIVER","ONRECEIVE");

    //Create a notification
    long notificationId = intent.getLongExtra("id", -1);

    if(notificationId == -1)
    {
        Log.e("AlarmReceiver","id went missing");
    }
    else
    {
        NotificationRepository repository = NotificationRepository.getInstance(context);
        Notification notification = repository.getNotification(notificationId);


        if(notification != null)
        {
            String[] icons = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icons);
            int iconId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(context.getPackageName()
                    + ":drawable/" + icons[notification.getIconIndex()], null, null);

            //create the android notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(iconId)
                    .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notification.getSubtitle())
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));

            if(notification.isPlaySound())
            {
                mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                Log.e("ALARMRECEIVER", "SOUND");
            }
            else Log.e("ALARMRECEIVER","NO SOUND");

            if (notification.isVibrate())
            {
                mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000});
            }

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify((int) notificationId, mBuilder.build());
            //Delete the notification from the database
            repository.removeNotification(notificationId);

            Intent i = new Intent("dvanack.gmail.com.NOTIFY");
            context.sendBroadcast(i);
            AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
            Log.w("ONRECEIVE","ENDED");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having this issue with Marshmallow and above.

There seems to be a problem with the below code :

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
    {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
    }
    else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime() , pendingIntent);
    }
```

here...the "else if" is not reachable since if the android version is marshmallow, it will again enter the first if condition only since the version is >=19. Hope this will solve the issue.

So the condition should be :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
{
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime() , pendingIntent);
}
else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
{
     alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Indeed! thank you very much, i'm pretty sure this will resolve the issue, i will test it asap

Comment: Please let me know of the results and please mark this as answer so that it will be helpful for others as well.